# Python enum.Enum: "TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Tags: python, enums, typeerror

When I run

```
import enum
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    FIRST = (1, 0)
    SECOND = (2, 1)
    THIRD = (3, 2)
    FOURTH = (4, 3)
    changeMe = (0, 5)
    def __init__(self, changeMe):
        self.changeMe.value[0] = changeMe
```

I get:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\enum.py", line 227, in __new__
    enum_member.__init__(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Can someone help me find out why this error is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Could we have the following of your code? Where do create a `MyEnum` Instance?

Comment: Welcome. What are you expect to get?

Comment: @AdrienKaczmarek looks like this error is raised on creation of the class itself, rather than on instance creation

Comment: Could you provide the full error?

Comment: You've redefined your `__init__` method in a way that it can't accept the arguments that are required to instantiate an enum. Thus, when the enum is created, it fails with the error you're seeing. Remove the `__init__` method and your code should work fine. If you require your `__init__` method, you probably shouldn't be creating an enum, as they generally don't have their value re-assigned during runtime.

Comment: Thank you @c.nivs for your clarification, I understand the problem now

Comment: Thank you @Stephen. I'll try to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your Enum, the value above your `__init__` are passed to the initiator.
Thus, you pass, for exemple, `FIRST = (1,0)`, add to this the `self`, so you obtain you 3 arguments.
However, in your `__init__` you are only looking for 2 argurment, 1 if you do look at the `self` one.

To correct this you could replace the first lines with the following scheme:

```
FIRST = (1,0) ==> FIRST = ([1,0])
```

Comment: When I do that, a new error occurs: `line 9, in __init__
    self.changeMe.value[0] = changeMe
AttributeError: 'MyEnum' object has no attribute 'changeMe'`

Thanks for answering, though!

Comment: I do not understand what you what to do with this `Enum`. You cannot change a value of an Enumerator, but you can built function on it that plays with its values. Could you describe a little bit more what you what to achieve so we can help you better?